# Adding an Access Point for Clients

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I want to add an AP for my Clients to be able to freely use the web.

I have a problem however is that I don't want them to access any computer or service on our Network..

Our layout is currently

WEB-Router --------LAN
192.168.10.254 ----192.168.10.x

I've tried to put an WiFi Router with the settings
WAN IP 192.168.10.253 and a DHCP for clients on wlan 192.168.1.1

But the problem is that if I connect to the WiFiRouter and get the IP 192.168.1.100 I'm still able to ping the network 192.168.10.0 and all its clients.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the WiFi Router might be NATTing the clients IP 192.168.1.x to 192.168.10.253, and this is the reason the traffic can go to and from the clients int the subnet 192.168.10.x.

If you disable NAT, then the client traffic from the WiFi router will keep the original IP address 192.168.1.x, and since the Web-Router does not know how to reach the 192.168.1.x subnet, it will not respond to the WLAN clients.